# SQL Server Stored Procedure insert query with given parameters

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

first of all, sorry for my English,

I am a newbie in stored procedure, so i'm seek for a help on it.

I have a project that need me to create a SP for a configurable table name and column name. I've manage to pass the table name and column name value from vb/vb.net and now i'm stuck on SP, below are sample of my code.

example :

```
frmTblname = table_a
frmClmnName = clm_A1, clm_A2, clm_A3, clm_A4, clm_A5,
toTblName = table_b,
toClmnName = clmn_b1,clmn_b2, clmn_b3, clmn_b4, clmn_b5
```

from vb/vb.net *`Rslt = ConnectionExec.RunSP(con, "sp_configurable_insert", frmTblname, frmClmnName, toTblName, toClmnName)`*

**how to add that into SQL insert query?**

Here are my SP

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[sp_configurable_insert] @fromTable nvarchar(50),@fromColumn nvarchar(4000),@toTable nvarchar(50),@toColumn nvarchar(4000)
```

I've tried this but it seems not giving any result.

```
set @Query1 = 'insert into '+@toTable+'('+quotename(@toColumn)+')   
    select top 20 '+@fromColumn+' 
from '+@fromTable+'
```

can anyone help me, please?

Thanks :)

Comment: First of all, show the full source of your SP, not just the part. Additionally it is bad practice to name stored procedures with the "sp_" prefix as this prefix commonly shows that this is the native MSSQL system procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things to change:

- `quotename(@toColumn)` will return '`[clmn_b1,clmn_b2, clmn_b3, clmn_b4, clmn_b5]'` which is not correct. Remove `quotename()` or set `@toColumn = '[clmn_b1], [clmn_b2], [clmn_b3], [clmn_b4], [clmn_b5]'`.
- your query statement is unfinished.

Stored procedure (with correct syntax):

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[sp_configurable_insert] 
    @fromTable nvarchar(50),
    @fromColumn nvarchar(4000),
    @toTable nvarchar(50),
    @toColumn nvarchar(4000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE 
        @stm nvarchar(max),
        @err int

    SET @stm = 
        N'insert into '+@toTable+' ('+@toColumn+') select top 20 '+@fromColumn+' from '+@fromTable
    EXEC @err = sp_executesql @stm
    IF @err <> 0 BEGIN
        RETURN @err
    END

    RETURN 0
END
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add EXECUTE(@Query1) to your SP and it will work

Answer (score 0):

Add at the end of your query:

```
exec sp_executesql @Query1
```

So it should look like:

```
set @Query1 = 'insert into '+@toTable+'('+quotename(@toColumn)+')   
    select top 20 '+@fromColumn+' 
from '+@fromTable+'

exec sp_executesql @Query1
```

So pay attention that @Query1 is incomplete or contains error coz quotes is unbalanced.